# What are yellow sushi radishes called?

Tags: food-identification, japanese-cuisine, radish

I'm considering growing some sushi radishes, but what are they called, because I'm considering growing some this summer after ordering them from a seed catalog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're talking about [takuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuan)? I don't know if I'd call it a sushi radish, but it's yellow and Japanese, at least.

It's just pickled daikon, not a naturally yellow radish:

> The finished takuan is usually yellow in color and quite pungent, though most mass-produced takuan uses salt or syrup to reduce the dehydration time, and is colored artificially.

You can have a look on [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=takuan&tbm=isch) to confirm it's what you're thinking of.

Comment: Yep, this one is at every Asian grocery I know: http://img.21food.com/img/product/2011/6/26/david720518-18420020.jpg